# Passing Parameter into Create in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to passsing Parameter to 'App\Http\Controllers\StoreController@create', but Laravel return error 404

i tried this on view:

```
<div class="text-end">
 <?php $id = $i->id; ?>
 <a href="{{ url('/store/create/' . $id) }}"
class="btn btn-primary text-end">Checkout</a>
</div>
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/store/create/{$id}','App\Http\Controllers\StoreController@create');
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Try removing the dollar sign from the route. `Route::get('/store/create/{id}'...`

Comment: @aynber i felt so dumb, its work thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Just Removing the dollar sign from the route. `Route::get('/store/create/{id}'`. Here we cann't use the dolla sign in routes w